# While updating google spreadsheet from google app script I am getting error message "You do not have permission to access the requested document."

Tags: google-apps-script

I have two environment for single google-app-script project. One with Sandbox and one with Production. Both have same code because, I copied Sandbox code into Production environment project.

Both are reading and writing same spreadsheet file with id `13vlLM5Tc7z4m-XXXXX-Kdjg`. Below is the sample code.

While I run my 'google-app-script' project as web application, update work fine with Sandbox env but it gives below error for production env.

> You do not have permission to access the requested document.

I check everything. I have full access of both 'google-app-script' project as well spreadsheet.

This is the code I used to find and update spreadsheet data.

```
var wb = '13vlLM5Tc7z4m-XXXXX-Kdjg';
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(wb);
var sheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
sheetData.shift();
var key = 'XYZ';
for(var i=0; i<sheetData.length; i++){
    if(key!=undefined && key!='' && key == sheetData[i][21]){
        resetPassUser = techSheetData[i];
        var values = [['Yes']];
        var nextRow = index+2; // get next row     
        sheet.getRange(nextRow, 23, 1, 1).setValues(values);
        break;
    }
}
```

It should update spreadsheet data using production env project also. Because code and permission are same. But instead it is giving me error.

> You do not have permission to access the requested document.

[image]

Comment: The pictured error seems to be with your `doGet()`, not the code you posted. Have you verified your web app publication settings and that the account you're using to access has permissions?

Comment: Please show the Execution transcript so we can see exactly when the error actually occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I think your authorization is confused. Try adding this to your app code

```
 /**
   * @NotOnlyCurrentDoc
   */
```